# use laravel view in wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, laravel, templates, view

I'm working on a project that requires showing a Laravel view in a Wordpress template. If possible I would like to do this without making Laravel part of the Wordpress installation. This is the template:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- laravel view goes here -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The iframe solution was unwanted. 'Technology too old' and i ran into header issues / same origin. So for now i opted for the full integration option. Which is described here. https://nehalist.io/integrating-laravel-into-wordpress/ (the right way, non-serviceprovider solution)

All pretty straightforward. Where i run into issues is how to access the laravel route that is displaying the view. So i have this wordpress installation that has a link to a website, which is also a wordpress installation with a custom solution to show users/images. This custom solution needs to be replaced by my laravel view. But how do i link to it from the first wordpress installation? Since it is now part of the second wordpress installation which has the following structure:

```
wp-admin/
wp-content/
wp-includes/
... other wordpress files ...
app/ <-- laravel application
|-> app/
|-> bootstrap/
|-> config/
|-> public/
|-> ... other laravel files and directories ...
```

Anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you use an iframe?

Comment: You need to use just a Blade template or part of Laravel app?

Comment: Well the laravel view is the result of accessing a route which leads to a controller which renders the view. So ideally i would like to access the route and get the view from there. So my guess is part of the laravel app.

Comment: You mean like this Laurel : <iframe src="urlToRouteThatReturnsLaravelView" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>?

Comment: @MartijnvanderBruggen something like that.

Comment: what you have done besides <!-- laravel view goes here --> ?

Comment: @vidal see my updated question plz.

Comment: the way you are doing this is somehow very complicated.. use an iframe or just do it in word press, you have 2 different systems that have different libraries and structure and you want them to integrate seamless I think thats not how they work... my opinion.

Comment: off the record, i think you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

I made a WordPress theme called [Laraish](https://github.com/laraish/laraish) to integrating Laravel into WordPress with WordPress specific routes. Maybe this can help you.